# QFileDialog "destroys" the name of the files

Tags: c++, qt, bioinformatics, fastq

Right now I'm working on a GUI for a suite of console applications used for bioinformatics and I'm doing my first tests as its my first project using Qt. I'm using QtDesigner for making the GUI and everything works perfectly except that QFileDialog converts the end of the file name into a strange character, although I'm not really sure if it is QFileDialog, or the conversion from **QString** *into **const char***.

Here is my code:

```
QString file=QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File"),"/home/",tr("Any file (*.*)"));
QString fastqdumpDir = "/home/nsg/Downloads/sratoolkit.2.1.16-centos_linux32/bin/"
fastqdumpDir=fastqdumpDir+"./fastq-dump ";
QString cmdStr =fastqdumpDir + file;
const char* command = cmdStr.toStdString().c_str();
system(command);
```

The fastq-dump program ends because it says that the filename is not correct, and after debugging, I see that the file name goes from **/home/nsg/Downloads/SRR502947.sra** into **/home/nsg/Downloads/SRR502947.sra[]** and sometimes even **/home/nsg/Downloads/SRR5029[]**

Any ideas why is this happening or how to fix it?

Comment: Those brackets are square ascii characters, not brackets, wont let me paste them here

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are calling `QString::toStdString()`, which returns a temporary object, and trying to get a pointer it's contents.  The memory pointed to becomes invalid as the `std::string` is destroyed.  You don't need to the intermediate `std::string` at all.  This should work:

```
QString cmdStr =fastqdumpDir + file;
system( qPrintable(cmdStr) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the system command to run the external program, you can use Qt's QProcess: -

```
QString cmdStr = fastqdumpDir + file;
QProcess::execute(cmdStr);
```

or

```
QProcess::startDetached(cmdStr)
```

if you don't want to wait for the process to finish. Since the functions take a QString, there's no need for the conversion to a const char*